# npm install of browser-sync errors

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2013, npm, browser-sync

First, the error:

```
  Error: Can't find "msbuild.exe".
```

The environment:

```
  node -v v0.12.7
  node-gyp -v v2.0.1   
  npm -v 2.11.3
```

I've gotten past this in the past by specifying --msvs_version=2013...it is not working now.

I've recently tried these other solutions to no avail.

```
  node-gyp configure --msvs_version=2013
  node-gyp build 

  #and this
  npm config set msvs_version 2013 --global
```